# RequestUsageExecutionTimeThreshold: what doing this property?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, client-object-model

Undocumented property: [SPClientCallableSettings.RequestUsageExecutionTimeThreshold](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spclientcallablesettings.requestusageexecutiontimethreshold.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

According to Reflector [SPClientCallableSettings.RequestUsageExecutionTimeThreshold property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spclientcallablesettings.requestusageexecutiontimethreshold.aspx) set or gets time threshold value in milliseconds. *If CSOM request time execution exceeds this value, then additional information is saved into ULS logs*

Answer (score 1):

this is a property from Microsoft.Sharepoint.Administration

you can check these links for more information

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/office/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spclientcallablesettings.requestusageexecutiontimethreshold

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/office/microsoft.sharepoint.administration

Comment: Thanks for the links, but what doing this property? Does anyone know?